# Setup a separate Google Analytics account for user pages within our site?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Each of our users can create websites within our website. They get their own subdomain off our main domain name as well. I was just going to track everything with a single Google Analytics account. Traffic will flow between the main site and users' websites. Then I thought to get a separate Google Analytics account for the set of users' websites.

Any reason to do one over the other? I'd love to track things like how visitors flow through the main site and users' sites. On the other hand, I'd also like to very easily just only see the statistics for our main site. Would be amazing to give our users access to analytics only for their webpages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single account and property with multiple profiles, so everybody gets the same on-page code.  From there, you can make a "global rollup" profile that takes all the traffic, and then setup individual profiles for each user's site and add an include filter to only accept data for their subdomain.

**tip:** by default GA only tracks the relative url (no domain) for the page name. To make it easier to see what page belongs to which domain in the global rollup, add a filter to the global rollup profile to add the domain to the page name.

And, you can give users access to just their profile.

**edit:** As Eike pointed out, a property is limited to 50 profiles, so if you have more users than that, there isn't an easy solution.

If shared data isn't a problem (e.g. all the users work for the same place and it doesn't matter if they are able to access other users' data), then you can just use a single profile and create segments based on the subdomain value.

If shared data *is* a problem, and you intend to have more than 50 users, you can do the same thing as above, but do not give them access to GA. Instead, create a scheduled report for a common report or 2 and have it emailed to them. This is limited and a bit inconvenient but those are the current limits of GA.

Comment: An account is limited to 50 profiles, though - might not be enough if there are many users.